# SharePoint 2016 (Onsite) Workflow

Tags: workflow, document-library, document, 2016, document-management

I wonder if someone has some user friendly guides on creating a workflow.

so the scenario is I have a large document library that will be visible to all. what i want to happen is:

User Creates or edits a document and for the new/edited document to be workflow to an approver before it is accessible to others.

In some cases there will be only one approver and in others there could be two or more.

can I have a workflow identify the approver based upon the metadata associated with the document? (I have enforced metadata insertion upon document creation/upload)

Thank you

Regards
Bev

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'd have to create a matrix with relations between metadata (I'd suggest to have choice list with finite number of options, e.g. a category of the document) and certain approvers.
Then the workflow should refer to that to properly direct the tasks.

Comment: Chris,

your suggestion sounds like a good idea,  could you provide the detail of how this can be achieved?

Regards
Bev

Comment: I don’t have an extensive experience with standard SP workflows so I can only tell how I’d solve it in solution I currently use (BPM platform for SharePoint). 
I’d create a SP list, first column to categorize the document (let’s say Doc. Type), the second column to specify person/people associated with given type of document. Then I’d use that SP list as a data source to provide options to choose from on the form level. Since I can use all information from the data source, then upon selecting the category the workflow would direct it to people specified in given row (dynamic task assignment)